# Google API: Difference between browser key and Android key?

Tags: android, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to use the Google Calendar API, and I've generated a browser API key that *seems* to work.  But in the API console I also have the option to generate an Android API key.  What is the difference between the two?  Can I use a browser key in an Android application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if it'll work to use a browser key in an Android application, but it doesn't really make sense.

From the [Google API docs](https://developers.google.com/console/help/#generatingdevkeys):

> The Console enables you to create server, browser, Android and iOS API
>   Keys. Once you've created a key, you restrict where it can be used.
>   The available restrictions depend upon the type of key.
>
> - Server keys can be restricted based on your servers' source IP address(es).
> - Browser keys can be restricted based on **HTTP referrer.**
> - Android keys can be restricted based on **the package name and certificate SHA-1 fingerprint.**
> - iOS keys can be restricted based on the bundle identifier.

It looks like you have to specify a website as the referrer for browser based keys. Since you don't know what the referrer will be in your Android app, it doesn't really make sense to do it this way. With an Android key, you can restrict API usage by the package name.

Also:

> Your project can therefore have server-side components in conjunction
>   with browser and/or mobile components, **without fear of compromising
>   your server(s) if a browser key or mobile key is compromised.**

If you use two different keys, it allows you to make sure if one is compromised, the others are not. This provides better security for you.

Comment: How would Google API's know that the request came from Android?  Do I have to put that data in the request rather than the URL like I'm doing now?

Comment: @crocboy No, it should know if it's coming from the browser because you're using the browser key, and if it's coming from an Android app because you're using the Android key. I don't think that a browser key will work in an Android app.

Comment: Thanks so much!  Your answer was very well written.

Answer (score 1):

The Difference is very well explained by @hichris123. However, for the second part of your question i would like to tell you that ideally you should not use browser key in android application.

But in a few scenarios, like while using place api in android, you will have to use browser key instead of android key as Place API only support browser key or server key. It does not support android or IOS key. And if you try to use android key the API will give you an error stating:

"This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 203.145.175.4, with empty referer"

So, in above case you will have to use browser key in your Android application.