# GCM api key using key for browser?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Now I use Key for browser applications as GOOGLE_API_KEY in my android app for GCM registration, before that I was using Key for Android applications and the result messages can be sent. I want to ask something

1. what different browser key & android key?
2. if I use the browser key for my android app, what long-term effects?

thanks..

Comment: Please refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24725018/google-api-difference-between-browser-key-and-android-key

Comment: http://tech-papers.org/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications-2/

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the Google API docs:

> The Console enables you to create server, browser, Android and iOS API Keys. Once you've created a key, you restrict where it can be used. The available restrictions depend upon the type of key.
>
> - Server keys can be restricted based on your servers' source IP address(es).
> - Browser keys can be restricted based on HTTP referrer.
> - Android keys can be restricted based on the package name and certificate SHA-1 fingerprint.
> - iOS keys can be restricted based on the bundle identifier.

Therefore by definition you will not be able to make use of browser key in Android code.

However, you can make use of classes like `HttpURLConnection` to kind of *simulate* a browser, thus allowing the use of browser keys in Android code as well.

So to wind up, if you use the keys in the wrong places(i.e. if you use browser key in cases where you don't make use of HTTP connections), the app won't even run.