# How many API keys do i need to use in android autoplace suggestion?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I used browser key and android key only but it will not working....
what number of different key do i need to used for autouggestion and get LatLng from that will placs name in suggestion.

private String getAutoCompleteUrl(String place) {

```
    // Obtain browser key from https://code.google.com/apis/console
    String key = "key=AIzaSyAVYq6kcBUABAtMIDil-8GDoDvWMi3QLnE";

    // place to be be searched
    String input = "input=" + place;

    // place type to be searched
    String types = "types=geocode";

    // Sensor enabled
    String sensor = "sensor=false";

    // Building the parameters to the web service
    String parameters = input + "&" + types + "&" + sensor + "&" + key;

    // Output format
    String output = "json";

    // Building the url to the web service
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/"
            + output + "?" + parameters;

    return url;
}
private String getPlaceDetailsUrl(String ref) {
    // Obtain browser key from https://code.google.com/apis/console
    String key = "key=AIzaSyAVYq6kcBUABAtMIDil-8GDoDvWMi3QLnE";
    // reference of place
    String reference = "reference=" + ref;
    // Sensor enabled
    String sensor = "sensor=false";
    // Building the parameters to the web service
    String parameters = reference + "&" + sensor + "&" + key;
    // Output format
    String output = "json";
    // Building the url to the web service
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/"
            + output + "?" + parameters;
    Log.d("url:",url);

    return url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need browser api key to get autocomplete place suggestions using the above method..
Below 2 tutorials will help you understand it in better way:

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-autocompletetextview-with-google-places-autocomplete-api/
OR
http://codetheory.in/google-place-api-autocomplete-service-in-android-application/

But if you are looking to use Google Places API for Android below tutorial explains it very clearly:

http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/android-places-api-autocomplete-getplacebyid/

And if you are looking for the difference between the two [browser and Android key]
this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24725198/2819262) pretty much explains it.

Hope it helps !!

Comment: @AmitaJain let me know if that helped?!

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if this works in all cases, but afaik you don't need a key anymore. So try this:

**String parameters = input + "&" + types + "&" + sensor;**